sodium_crypto_pwhash gives a different result in PHP and in node.js
I'm trying to encrypt a string on the front-end (node.js electron) and trying to decrypt it on the back-end (PHP) using sodium (I've tried libsodium-wrappers and sodium-plus).
Everything looks good on the back-end when the front-end messages it, except the sodium_crypto_pwhash() function gives a different value to the crypto_pwhash() function on the front-end, and the decryption fails.
Can anyone tell me why the two are different?
Front-end code (javascript):
  nonce = await sodium.randombytes_buf(24); 
  salt = await sodium.randombytes_buf(16);

  key = await sodium.crypto_pwhash(
       32,
       password,
       salt,
       3, //sodium.CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
       268435456, //sodium.CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
       sodium.SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_ALG_ARGON2ID13
  );

 let ciphertext = await sodium.crypto_secretbox(data, nonce, key);

 var assembledParts = Buffer.concat([salt, nonce, ciphertext]);
 var encryptedtext = assembledParts.toString('base64');
 return encryptedtext;

back-end code (PHP):
public function decrypt(string $encrypted, string $password): string
    {
        try {
            
            $decoded = sodium_base642bin($encrypted, SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL);

            $salt = mb_substr($decoded, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES, '8bit');
            $nonce = mb_substr(
                $decoded,
                SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES,
                SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES,
                '8bit'
            );

            $ciphertext = mb_substr(
                $decoded,
                SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES + SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES,
                null,
                '8bit'
            );

            $key = sodium_crypto_pwhash(
                32, //SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES,
                $password,
                $salt,
                3, //SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_MODERATE,
                268435456, //SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_MODERATE
                SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_ALG_ARGON2ID13
            );

            $decrypted = sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($ciphertext, $nonce, $key);
            if ($decrypted === false) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Could not decrypt data.');
            }

            return $decrypted;
        } catch (SodiumException $e) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Could not decrypt data.', 0, $e);
        }
    }

The front-end says:
password: password
salt: 99d7ca2fb1f2de31af83aec47d72a597
nonce: 84dd6c469cb7beee7cf470914e60cd5e08eb5ffbbf952f7d
key: bc8920e4c004f4b2e7096a3fd8d06233350920402565822b7e65e27312aac1d8
ciphertext: d9c13a6ec90b2b3c93463db4e24a4f2fc897f5367c39e6bb80f19286cb78
encryptedtext: mdfKL7Hy3jGvg67EfXKll4TdbEact77ufPRwkU5gzV4I61/7v5UvfdnBOm7JCys8k0Y9tOJKTy/Il/U2fDnmu4DxkobLeA==
The back-end says:
payload: 99d7ca2fb1f2de31af83aec47d72a59784dd6c469cb7beee7cf470914e60cd5e08eb5ffbbf952f7dd9c13a6ec90b2b3c93463db4e24a4f2fc897f5367c39e6bb80f19286cb78
salt: 99d7ca2fb1f2de31af83aec47d72a597
nonce: 84dd6c469cb7beee7cf470914e60cd5e08eb5ffbbf952f7d
ciphertext: d9c13a6ec90b2b3c93463db4e24a4f2fc897f5367c39e6bb80f19286cb78
key: 20046154897da0689c3dfbbb8bb5c1fa8253673229c3731d67727951f2b0f79d
With the mismatched pwhashes, the back-end gives an error during decryption.
I have replaced the defined constants on both sides with their numeric values and I have changed both sides from default algorithm to specifically select SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_ALG_ARGON2ID13
Neither one made a difference.
I have also tried libsodium-wrappers and sodium-plus on the front-end. Neither seemed to result in a difference.

On the back-end, what is “payload”? I’d expect it to be the output of encryption on the front-end, which is base64 encoded but instead looks like hex.

It's the entire encrypted string received by the back-end function before any of the slicing happens. I have hex-encoded the result of the B64 decode. It's defined like this:
$payload= sodium_bin2hex(sodium_base642bin($encrypted, SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL));
You can see the salt, nonce, and cipertext inside the payload hex string.

Okay, thanks for the clarification, I was trying to match your debugging with variable names

So, you are trying to use secret box with a controlled password that you just hash (with salt) to make it fit? Am I reading that correct? I’m not aware of that usage, only the version where to generate a fully random key that both sides securely store, or the public key versions such as sodium_crypto_box. Have you tested decrypting your version in JS, just to confirm it is working there?

Yes, it's just a dummy password right now, trying to keep the model simple to show the problem. I'm having a similar issue with the asymmetrical functions. I have JS-JS working and PHP-PHP working, which I put down to the pwhash function working consistently on each platform but not across platforms.

The problem is not reproducible, the PHP code successfully decrypts the data of the NodeJS code. In particular, the same key is generated (i.e. pwhash() returns the same value), see online https://paiza.io/projects/x4TJPN0J1v7HWTc3MaEVlg.

Thanks Topaco, that's handy to know. I am going to play with the config of the PHP on the server in that case.
